# Spread Parameters<T> onto T without Typescript complaining

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've made a function for rendering a prop which may or may not be a React render prop/function:

```
import { isValidElement } from 'react';

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
type AnyFunction = (...args: any) => any;

export function isRenderFunction<F extends AnyFunction>(
  subject: React.ReactNode | F
): subject is F {
  return !isValidElement(subject) && subject instanceof Function;
}
export function render<F extends AnyFunction>(
  subject: React.ReactNode | F,
  ...parameters: Parameters<F>
): React.ReactNode {
  return isRenderFunction(subject)
    ? subject(
        // @ts-ignore
        ...parameters
      )
    : subject ?? null;
}
```

The function works fine, but without that `// @ts-ignore` I'm getting the following error:

> Type 'Parameters' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator.ts(2488)

I can make this error go away by changing to `Parameters<F>[]`, i.e. typing it as an array, but then all the usages of the `render` function complains instead.

---

**Playground Link:**
[Provided](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=22#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVzQQwBtCAeAMTlBmBQBMBnOACgDo38oBzegLjnxQBPAJRwAvAD5+QiUwBQcRCj5kANArhsWYDvgC2walF5wACroNH65CXOF8ASoaRQUAFUFhgNuAG8NUM6uSqxsOlD6hsDGwgDccgC+QA)

---

**Solution:**
Based on accepted answer, I pulled out some "helper types", and ended up with this, which seems to work pretty good both code- and type-wise.

```
import { ReactNode, isValidElement } from 'react';

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
type AnyArg = any;

export type RenderFunction<A extends AnyArg[]> = (...args: A) => ReactNode;
export type RenderProp<A extends AnyArg[]> = ReactNode | RenderFunction<A>;

export function isRenderFunction<A extends AnyArg[]>(
  subject: RenderProp<A>
): subject is RenderFunction<A> {
  return !isValidElement(subject) && subject instanceof Function;
}

export function render<A extends AnyArg[]>(
  subject: RenderProp<A>,
  ...parameters: A
): ReactNode {
  return isRenderFunction(subject) ? subject(...parameters) : subject ?? null;
}
```

Comment: [I can't seem to recreate the issue](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5gGImQbwChkTkAKOALmSylAHMAaZAI2pAFcBbF6ZharQYBKagDcA9sAAmhAL6FFCCSCzJgXAA4Abauiy5kAXmQwOIBGGAryVGmDogmrdt15R+ghyPFTpBYlJlVQltCAA6bQl6CmYWfmEAbnklFTU4KHoMagAFDLguCEgoDAAefRwQAD5jZABtACI4BuYARmYGlgaAXWSNHTJwoYyspKA). Just did a variable that holds `Parameters` and I'm able to spread it. Could it be tied to your TS version?

Comment: @VLAZ this has something todo with generic type constraint. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzsAzgNQIYBtgBMCiWApiEQHbwC+cAZlBCHAORREYDGMTA3AFCiRYcAFRwMKOACU2nWvUYsZXPrxgBPMETgBBMmoBiAVzKdgEMnAC8cABQA6BxigBzFAC4xegJRWAfJ7UVIgAPQXgaY1NzZBRpMlwiKCMTGDMyAB59OBCYclwJXQNI1PNfG144OBRDACMAKyJOD2kOGDsWzgA5CAS4AB84fV4vD2r6xvhUQcQKuFYYQygLAEJUTBwCYlIKGzGGzh8AMkOq2v3JshQYDBMiCBpB4rS+Sl5eELDaJ+jWeMTM7LBXLxAp6ZJRMhlWZ7CbNJTtJTdXoDfQAGlmDjsYCcGFIuSg7jgAAUcXjEihMr5hnDWgjWkitAhZvNFhZUHEEklvmRdmcJl5ZpUAPyncaccqVSWSzHYqC4oj4lCCyUCqWjPmyIUisiGLBYF5AA)

Comment: @VLAZ Added link to typescript playground showing the error 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the function to not use `Parameters`. `Parameters` being a conditional type can't be resolved until it does not contain any more type parameters, so it you use it you will need an assertion.

The version without `Parameters` would be:

```
import React, { isValidElement } from 'react';



export function isRenderFunction<P extends any[]>(
  subject: React.ReactNode | ((...p: P) => React.ReactNode)
): subject is ((...p: P) => React.ReactNode) {
  return !isValidElement(subject) && subject instanceof Function;
}
export function render<P extends any[]>(
  subject: React.ReactNode | ((...p: P) => React.ReactNode),
  ...parameters: P
): React.ReactNode {
  return isRenderFunction(subject)
    ? subject(
        ...parameters
      )
    : subject ?? null;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=19&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDedgDOAaigDbAAmAoqUiEgHbwC+cAZlBCHAORSoYeAbgCwAKHGSxSAB6RY7AK4MMwCA3wFkDCkigAxZavUAeAApxZMRhQJwUDAJ4BtALoA+ABTi4cAooAjACskDAAuRAEYADpkdBgAOQhdOAAfOE9PaOywCLMASjgAXndI+NiopN188XyI-2DQ+EIMrJy8wpKyjAr4qqRCnB84fhhFKA0AQkIScmpaeiZPBpCMQoAydb9A1eaGAhgHNCQINjhDFRg1BlExZnFZeXg2Iyv1EZs9c0sZax07BwuDzeMS+FZNCJxHpQxLJJBpVrZaK5OAFYqlGG9DD9fKYYZIsAoKAoejWKAEPK1SFRLGwlJDUEfMYTTTaXQGV7XZY7Jo1Rm+AD820aGBBvnF4oJRJJSDJBGGEr5EvqPIwcAFQoYilIpFuzCAA)

Answer (score 1):

Also ran into this recently, the problem is actually this line;

```
type AnyFunction = (...args: any) => any;
```

Specifically, for `...args`

- We've told TypeScript it is `any`; which means it could be non-Iterable
- We know it is an Iterable as we used a rest operator on it

The type we should use is therefore `any[]`

So **the solution is**;

```
type AnyFunction = (...args: any[]) => any;
```